# Is it possible to run the command line compiler with selected build configuration in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, build, delphi-xe2, buildconfiguration

I'd like to make builds from the command line and I'm wondering if there's a way how to execute the command line compiler with selected build configuration ?

I know there is option --no-config which won't load default dcc32.cfg file but I would like to set the build configuration I've prepared in my project.

I would like to run something like

```
dcc32.exe --some-option RELEASE Win32 PLATFORM
```

Is there some option for selecting build configuration ?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be using `msbuild` rather than `dcc32` for this:

```
msbuild myproject.dproj /p:Config=RELEASE;Platform=Win32
```

Make sure you have called the `rsvars.bat` file from the RAD Studio `bin` folder before you attempt to call `msbuild`. This sets up the necessary environment variables.

The great thing about the modern `msbuild` based build system, as implemented in Delphi, is that you can quite easily ensure that your command line builds are identical to your IDE builds.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I have to wait 2 minutes to accept :)

Comment: DCC32 was the right way in Delphi 7, and MSBUILD is the way since Delphi 2007, up to now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can use the dcc64.exe to compile for 64-bit if you do not want to use MSBuild. It is in the same folder as the dcc32.exe (and dccosx.exe for compile for OSX)